# String[] cant be converted to String;

Tags: java, arrays, string, massive

I'm trying to split Array strs to another but error

```
class Solution {
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        String[][] letters;
**        String cmon;
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            letters[i][i] = strs[i].split("");
        }**

        for (int j = 0; j < letters[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
                if (letters[k][j] == letters[k++][j]) {
                    cmon = letters[j][k];
                }  else {
                    cmon = "";
                }
            }
        }
        return cmon;
    }
}
```

```
Line 6: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String
            letters[i][i] = strs[i].toString().split("");
                                                    ^
```

changed code a lot but nothing happend. already tried methods from stackoverflow but it doesnt help

Comment: `letters[i][i]` would be a single String.  `split` returns multiple Strings.  You can’t store multiple Strings in one String variable.  You probably wanted `letters[i]`.  However, you will find that that is not enough;  the compiler will inform you that you never initialized `letters` at all.  Change your declaration to `String[][] letters = new String[strs.length][];`.  Also, your second pair of loops are assigning a one-character string to `cmon`, which I’m pretty sure will not be what you want to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I'm trying to split Array strs to another but error ..."*

The *[split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* method is for a *[String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)* *object* specifically.

Use a *char array* for this.

```java
char[][] letters = new char[strs.length][];
for (int i = 0, n = strs.length; i < n; i++)
    letters[i] = strs[i].toCharArray();
```